# Aligning elements to the bottom of the page or div in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to use sliding panel in application. I am using following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
```

The code what i shared is just expanding the div from its actual position to the downward direction. But I want the div to be expanded from its actual position to the upward direction. I hope you understand what i mean. Please help me

Comment: More details please. Post your html / css or fiddle.

Comment: Since HTML elements are rendered one after another in document normal flow, it depends on your markups. please provide more info.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  $('#panel').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4Haq/)

Then to make it toggle like action check if visible

```
if($('#panel').is(':visible')){
  $('#panel').hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
}else{
  $('#panel').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The others are good answers, but I decided to add a version which uses css3 transition as they are smoother and I think we should be using them to move the web forward:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/wQwkz/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $('.elem').addClass('shown');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
});
});
```